# Pyspark StreamingQueryException local using query.awaitTermination() - local netcat stream combined with Pyspark app on jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, netcat

I've just tried out a basic piece of code for a pyspark (version 3.0.1) streaming example on my Lubuntu 20.04 LTS system using python 3.9x.

I opened a new jupyter notebook in GoogleChrome, started with the following code (the part which doesn't throw an error yet):

```
# Import modules
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode, split

#%%
## SCRIPT

# Instantiate the new spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("StreamingDemo").getOrCreate()

# Call stream with sending messages to local host with standard port "9999"
# --> loads socket
lines = spark.readStream.format("socket").option("host", "local").option("port", 9999).load()

# Create dataframe
# NOTE on several methods employed here (hover over them for docs)
words = lines.select(explode(split(lines.value, " ")).alias("word"))

# Create word counter
wordCounts = words.groupBy("word").count()

# Print result
print(wordCounts.printSchema())

# Create output mode for the stream (hover over functions for docs)
om = wordCounts.writeStream.outputMode("complete")

# Create query for the output-mode
# NOTE on output format: can also be "json" if further processing is needed
query = om.format("console").start()
```

Output in console:

```
[I 18:21:45.684 NotebookApp] Kernel restarted: f55c9433-3ae9-45f0-b34b-a1123e2899b0
[I 18:21:45.719 NotebookApp] Restoring connection for f55c9433-3ae9-45f0-b34b-a1123e2899b0:4417bfd825454f4790078827ccc529df
[I 18:21:45.720 NotebookApp] Replaying 3 buffered messages
[I 18:21:48.797 NotebookApp] Saving file at /Untitled.ipynb
20/12/20 18:21:57 WARN Utils: Your hostname, andylu-Lubuntu-PC resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.1.1; using 192.168.1.98 instead (on interface wlp3s0)
20/12/20 18:21:57 WARN Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform (file:/home/andylu/.pyenv/versions/3.9.0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/jars/spark-unsafe_2.12-3.0.1.jar) to constructor java.nio.DirectByteBuffer(long,int)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
20/12/20 18:21:59 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
20/12/20 18:22:04 WARN TextSocketSourceProvider: The socket source should not be used for production applications! It does not support recovery.
20/12/20 18:22:07 WARN StreamingQueryManager: Temporary checkpoint location created which is deleted normally when the query didn't fail: /tmp/temporary-0843cc22-4f7c-4b2e-a6ef-3ba5aa16ec08. If it's required to delete it under any circumstances, please set spark.sql.streaming.forceDeleteTempCheckpointLocation to true. Important to know deleting temp checkpoint folder is best effort.
20/12/20 18:22:08 ERROR MicroBatchExecution: Query [id = c5d1875b-7c4e-4ff2-a922-af871b311812, runId = 79c0726b-4457-4c3d-b81f-04f36bc8eedd] terminated with error
java.net.UnknownHostException: local
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:220)
        at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:403)
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609)
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:558)
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:454)
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:231)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.sources.TextSocketMicroBatchStream.initialize(TextSocketMicroBatchStream.scala:71)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.sources.TextSocketMicroBatchStream.planInputPartitions(TextSocketMicroBatchStream.scala:117)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.MicroBatchScanExec.partitions$lzycompute(MicroBatchScanExec.scala:44)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.MicroBatchScanExec.partitions(MicroBatchScanExec.scala:44)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataSourceV2ScanExecBase.supportsColumnar(DataSourceV2ScanExecBase.scala:61)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataSourceV2ScanExecBase.supportsColumnar$(DataSourceV2ScanExecBase.scala:60)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.MicroBatchScanExec.supportsColumnar(MicroBatchScanExec.scala:29)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataSourceV2Strategy.apply(DataSourceV2Strategy.scala:91)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.$anonfun$plan$1(QueryPlanner.scala:63)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.nextCur(Iterator.scala:484)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:490)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:489)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.plan(QueryPlanner.scala:93)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkStrategies.plan(SparkStrategies.scala:68)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.$anonfun$plan$3(QueryPlanner.scala:78)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.$anonfun$foldLeft$1(TraversableOnce.scala:162)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.$anonfun$foldLeft$1$adapted(TraversableOnce.scala:162)
        at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:941)
        at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:941)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1429)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.foldLeft(TraversableOnce.scala:162)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.foldLeft$(TraversableOnce.scala:160)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foldLeft(Iterator.scala:1429)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.$anonfun$plan$2(QueryPlanner.scala:75)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.nextCur(Iterator.scala:484)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:490)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.plan(QueryPlanner.scala:93)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkStrategies.plan(SparkStrategies.scala:68)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.$anonfun$plan$3(QueryPlanner.scala:78)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.$anonfun$foldLeft$1(TraversableOnce.scala:162)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.$anonfun$foldLeft$1$adapted(TraversableOnce.scala:162)
        at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:941)
        at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:941)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1429)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.foldLeft(TraversableOnce.scala:162)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.foldLeft$(TraversableOnce.scala:160)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foldLeft(Iterator.scala:1429)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.$anonfun$plan$2(QueryPlanner.scala:75)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.nextCur(Iterator.scala:484)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:490)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.plan(QueryPlanner.scala:93)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkStrategies.plan(SparkStrategies.scala:68)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.$anonfun$plan$3(QueryPlanner.scala:78)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.$anonfun$foldLeft$1(TraversableOnce.scala:162)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.$anonfun$foldLeft$1$adapted(TraversableOnce.scala:162)
        at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:941)
        at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:941)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1429)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.foldLeft(TraversableOnce.scala:162)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.foldLeft$(TraversableOnce.scala:160)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foldLeft(Iterator.scala:1429)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.$anonfun$plan$2(QueryPlanner.scala:75)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.nextCur(Iterator.scala:484)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:490)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.plan(QueryPlanner.scala:93)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkStrategies.plan(SparkStrategies.scala:68)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.$anonfun$plan$3(QueryPlanner.scala:78)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.$anonfun$foldLeft$1(TraversableOnce.scala:162)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.$anonfun$foldLeft$1$adapted(TraversableOnce.scala:162)
        at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:941)
        at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:941)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1429)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.foldLeft(TraversableOnce.scala:162)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.foldLeft$(TraversableOnce.scala:160)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foldLeft(Iterator.scala:1429)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.$anonfun$plan$2(QueryPlanner.scala:75)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.nextCur(Iterator.scala:484)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:490)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.plan(QueryPlanner.scala:93)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkStrategies.plan(SparkStrategies.scala:68)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$.createSparkPlan(QueryExecution.scala:330)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$sparkPlan$1(QueryExecution.scala:94)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker.measurePhase(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:111)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$executePhase$1(QueryExecution.scala:133)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:764)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executePhase(QueryExecution.scala:133)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.sparkPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:94)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.sparkPlan(QueryExecution.scala:87)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$executedPlan$1(QueryExecution.scala:107)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker.measurePhase(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:111)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$executePhase$1(QueryExecution.scala:133)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:764)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executePhase(QueryExecution.scala:133)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:107)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan(QueryExecution.scala:100)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runBatch$14(MicroBatchExecution.scala:563)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:352)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken$(ProgressReporter.scala:350)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:69)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.runBatch(MicroBatchExecution.scala:553)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runActivatedStream$2(MicroBatchExecution.scala:223)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:352)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken$(ProgressReporter.scala:350)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:69)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1(MicroBatchExecution.scala:191)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProcessingTimeExecutor.execute(TriggerExecutor.scala:57)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.runActivatedStream(MicroBatchExecution.scala:185)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runStream(StreamExecution.scala:334)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:245)
```

Next, the problematic line gets executed:

```
query.awaitTermination()
```

It throws the following exception:

```
StreamingQueryException                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-885fef5a9f37> in <module>
----> 1 query.awaitTermination()

~/.pyenv/versions/3.9.0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/sql/streaming.py in awaitTermination(self, timeout)
    101             return self._jsq.awaitTermination(int(timeout * 1000))
    102         else:
--> 103             return self._jsq.awaitTermination()
    104 
    105     @property

~/.pyenv/versions/3.9.0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1302 
   1303         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1304         return_value = get_return_value(
   1305             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1306 

~/.pyenv/versions/3.9.0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
    132                 # Hide where the exception came from that shows a non-Pythonic
    133                 # JVM exception message.
--> 134                 raise_from(converted)
    135             else:
    136                 raise

~/.pyenv/versions/3.9.0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py in raise_from(e)

StreamingQueryException: local
=== Streaming Query ===
Identifier: [id = c5d1875b-7c4e-4ff2-a922-af871b311812, runId = 79c0726b-4457-4c3d-b81f-04f36bc8eedd]
Current Committed Offsets: {}
Current Available Offsets: {TextSocketV2[host: local, port: 9999]: -1}

Current State: ACTIVE
Thread State: RUNNABLE

Logical Plan:
WriteToMicroBatchDataSource ConsoleWriter[numRows=20, truncate=true]
+- Aggregate [word#3], [word#3, count(1) AS count#7L]
   +- Project [word#3]
      +- Generate explode(split(value#0,  , -1)), false, [word#3]
         +- StreamingDataSourceV2Relation [value#0], org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.sources.TextSocketTable$$anon$1@14d00623, TextSocketV2[host: local, port: 9999]
```

Actually, I should be able to use this stream like so (opening another terminal instance):

```
nc -lk 9999
```

There then, it should be possible to type in e.g. "Hello Andreas" and get a word count output in the jupyter notebook console containing the stream. Yet, I can't find a way to get around this error.

---

**EDIT on additional things tried out:**

*First*, I changed the hostname "host" to "localhost", as this seems to be recognized as the standard term.

*Next*, as suggested below by @Mazahir Hussain, I tried the following (replacing `lines` with `wordCounts` since this is my target):

```
query = wordCounts \
.writeStream \
.outputMode("append") \
.format("console") \
.option("checkpointLocation", "/tmp/dtn2/checkpoint")\
.start()
```

However, the "append"-mode throws the following Exception:

```
AnalysisException: Append output mode not supported when there are streaming aggregations on streaming DataFrames/DataSets without watermark;;
Aggregate [word#3], [word#3, count(1) AS count#7L]
+- Project [word#3]
   +- Generate explode(split(value#0,  , -1)), false, [word#3]
      +- StreamingRelationV2 org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.sources.TextSocketSourceProvider@167d70f6, socket, org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.sources.TextSocketTable@695149a6, org.apache.spark.sql.util.CaseInsensitiveStringMap@b832311b, [value#0]
```

So I changed the mode from "append" to "complete" to avoid that error.

Yet, when carrying out `query.awaitTermination()`, another error is thrown:

```
StreamingQueryException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
=== Streaming Query ===
Identifier: [id = c5843d59-0f89-4974-a694-9f9ae36cf4fe, runId = 5d43c468-ce55-4f8c-b41a-d60f6e053ade]
Current Committed Offsets: {}
Current Available Offsets: {TextSocketV2[host: localhost, port: 9999]: -1}

Current State: ACTIVE
Thread State: RUNNABLE

Logical Plan:
WriteToMicroBatchDataSource ConsoleWriter[numRows=20, truncate=true]
+- Aggregate [word#3], [word#3, count(1) AS count#7L]
   +- Project [word#3]
      +- Generate explode(split(value#0,  , -1)), false, [word#3]
         +- StreamingDataSourceV2Relation [value#0], org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.sources.TextSocketTable$$anon$1@5914e8ff, TextSocketV2[host: localhost, port: 9999]
```

Conclusively, the suggestion of @Mazahir Hussain to implement `.option("checkpointLocation", "/tmp/dtn2/checkpoint")` was not the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the beginning, open the code as a jupyter notebook in a new UNIX-terminal:

```
jupyter notebook "scriptname.ipynb"
```

Next, run the following code within it:

```
# Import modules
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode, split

#%%
## SCRIPT

# Instantiate the new spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("StreamingDemo").getOrCreate()

# * Call stream with sending messages to local host with standard port "9999"
# --> loads socket
# NOTE on hosthame: use "localhost" being the standard term for working locally on your private computer ("local" apparently doesn't work correctly)
lines = spark.readStream.format("socket").option("host", "localhost").option("port", 9999).load()

# Create dataframe
# NOTE on several methods employed here (hover over them for docs)
words = lines.select(explode(split(lines.value, " ")).alias("word"))

# Create word counter
# NOTE: store in a new dataframe
wordCounts = words.groupBy("word").count()

# * Print results
print(wordCounts.printSchema())
# NOTE on printing out the head: it doesn't work here, but throws the following AnalysisException:
# "method: AnalysisException: Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start();;socket"
# --> this seems to function after initiating an actual streaming query
#print(wordCounts.head(5))
```

Now, open a `UNIX`-terminal and start a [netcat](https://linuxize.com/post/netcat-nc-command-with-examples/) streaming connection like so:

```
nc -lk 9999
```

Therein, type some words you would like to be streamed, and hit enter successively, such as:

```
hallo world
blabla
```

Next, return to the jupyter notebook and run the last piece of code in order to start a query:

```
# * Create query for the stream * #
# NOTE on output format: can also be "json" or "memory" if further processing is needed
# NOTE on options "append" and "complete":
# - complete: doesn't need unique counts, e.g. typing in Hello Andreas and then Hello Rikkert counts Hello twice
# - append: only new elements will be considered
query = wordCounts.writeStream.outputMode("complete").format("console").start()
query.awaitTermination()
```

Now, the other open terminal session of the juypter notebook should be updated like so:

```
-------------------------------------------                                     
Batch: 0
-------------------------------------------
+----+-----+
|word|count|
+----+-----+
+----+-----+

-------------------------------------------                                     
Batch: 1
-------------------------------------------
+------+-----+
|  word|count|
+------+-----+
| hello|    1|
|blabla|    1|
| world|    1|
+------+-----+
```

You can type anything you want to see the batch word count being update in the jupyter notebook terminal session accordingly.

To end the process, press `CTRL + C` first in the `netcat`-terminal session, then in the `jupyter notebook` session, if needed.

As a conclusion, it was only necessary to know when exactly to start the streaming via netcat and also that the `jupyter notebook` must be started via another `UNIX`-terminal to show interactive batch-updating whenever words are being input in the `netcat` terminal session.

---

**PS on local hostname:**

When using "local" instead of "localhost", it'll throw the following exception, so make sure you call your host *"localhost"* in this context:

```
StreamingQueryException: local
=== Streaming Query ===
Identifier: [id = d4226889-efd8-4992-86e0-2064e7fd45ae, runId = 7b626410-d764-4b53-a8ad-1850b6f0ddd0]
Current Committed Offsets: {}
Current Available Offsets: {TextSocketV2[host: local, port: 9999]: -1}

Current State: ACTIVE
Thread State: RUNNABLE

Logical Plan:
WriteToMicroBatchDataSource ConsoleWriter[numRows=20, truncate=true]
+- Aggregate [word#3], [word#3, count(1) AS count#7L]
   +- Project [word#3]
      +- Generate explode(split(value#0,  , -1)), false, [word#3]
         +- StreamingDataSourceV2Relation [value#0], org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.sources.TextSocketTable$$anon$1@262f8557, TextSocketV2[host: local, port: 9999]
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a checkpoint directory in /tmp/ and then set the path
e.g. I have created dir "dtn2" and "checkpoint"

```
query = lines \
.writeStream \
.outputMode("append") \
.format("console") \
.option("checkpointLocation", "/tmp/dtn2/checkpoint")\
.start()
```

query.awaitTermination()

**Note**: you must you have to add checkpointlocation in your code

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I've tried it out (see edit of my initial question), unfortunately it was not the solution. Later, I found the reason for the problem and posted an answer, thanks for your effort nevertheless.